# What does "<+" mean in this code?

Tags: javascript

I encountered this strange supposed operator and am having trouble figuring out what it is. Any ideas?

```
var laugh = function(num){
var string=""; 
    for (i=0; i<+num; i++) {
    string+="ha";  
    }
return string + "!"; 
};

console.log(laugh(10));
```

Comment: this '<' operator simple means smaller. The question should be "what does it mean for +num'" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<+` is not an operator. You may interpret it simply as `for (i=0; i < +num; i++)` where `+` is the unary plus operator. The unary plus operator will coerce `num` into a number.

For example, if the value passed to `num` was `"100"` (as a `String`), the unary plus operator would coerce it to `100` (a `Number`).

[MDN contains some examples of unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) and other arithmetic operators.

Answer (score 4):

One of the purposes of the `+` sign in JS is to parse the right part into the number.

```js
const str = '4';
console.log(str + 5); // Concatenared as strings
console.log(+str + 5); // Sums the numbers
```

In your case you have an statement `i < +num`, which just parses `num` into number and `i` compares with it. If your `num` is a number, this will do nothing.

Look. I have used `'10'` instead of `10` and it still works, because the given string is parsed into number.

```js
var laugh = function(num) {
   var string=""; 
   for (var i = 0; i < +num; i++) {
      string+="ha";  
   }
   
   return string + "!"; 
};

console.log(laugh('10'));
```

Comment: `'10'` will work even without `+` in `+num`

Comment: You are right. `<` do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

This is the way this is parsed;

```
i < +num
```

In other words, `num` is being coerced to an integer before `<` is run on it.

There is no `<+`. They are parsed as separate symbols.